# About Direct2D and DirectWrite features

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, directx

Is anybody know how to enable Direct2D and DirectWrite features in XP and Vista? Direct2D and DirectWrite were introduced in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what Microsoft has announced at this point, neither of these will be available in XP, but will be added to Vista upon their release.

For details on DirectWrite (in particular, being released for Vista but not XP), see [this MSDN blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2009/04/13/directwrite-questions-and-answers.aspx)

Direct2D is built on DirectX 10.1, so will not work on XP (since DirectX 10 is Vista+ only).

Direct2D and DirectWrite technical previews are both currently available in the [March 2009 DirectX SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24a541d6-0486-4453-8641-1eee9e21b282&displaylang=en)  They will work today (as a tech preview) in Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is unofficial, may contain malwares/virus but it's there: [DirectX 10 for Windows XP](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/download-directx-10-for-windows-xp-from-alky-project/). I did not test it.